# Same transparency with overlapping patches

Tags: matlab, plot, transparency, opacity, matlab-figure

I have a geometric figure with a complex shape. However, it can be split into several simpler subfigures. I need to plot them with some transparency, so I use patches. However, in the overlapping areas the color is too dark, as (of course) the patches overlap.

MWE

```
patch([0.1 0.45 0.45 0.1], [0.65 0.65 0.85 0.85], 'black', 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
patch([0.35 0.55 0.55 0.35], [0.4 0.4 0.8 0.8], 'black', 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
alpha(0.6)
```

[image]

How do I achieve a uniform opacity? I am open to other approaches different from patches.

Comment: I know people can run your [mcve] but you should add a picture to the question to better portray what it is you are talking about.

Comment: As it was only 3 lines of code I guessed it would be unnecessary. I edited anyway.

Comment: So you want the intersection area to be medium grey instead of dark grey? Don't use transparency and set the patch color as grey directly; is that acceptable for you? Or do you need transparency for other reasons?

Comment: I am using patches because I put this figure over others and I need to see both (in that case it's ok to have overlapping colors).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the patches however for complex shapes this may be hard to accomplish.

```
x=[0.1 0.45 0.45 0.55 0.55 0.35 0.35 0.1];
y=[0.85 0.85 0.8 0.8 0.4 0.4 0.65 0.65];
patch(x,y,'k','FaceAlpha',0.6,'LineStyle','none')
```